# Missing Security Credentials tab in IAM console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Trying to reset my IAM access key. Per [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey), there supposed to be a Security Credentials tab after selecting the user, but it does not show. Here are the steps I'm performing:

1. Sign in to AWS console and open IAM console
2. In the navigation pane, choose Users
3. Choose the name of the desired user, and then choose the Security Credentials tab

After selecting the user, there is no security tab. My user has the following permissions policy:

AdministratorAccess policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Screenshot after selecting user:

[image: Screenshot after selecting user]

Comment: You're not on the right page. In your screenshot, find your desired user and click the name of the user.

Comment: Thanks @MattHouser, I did not realize I must click on the name of the user (as opposed to the row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't see the security credentials tab when you list the users. To configure the columns, click on `Manage Columns` icon on top right.

[image]

Then select the columns you want to be displayed:

[image]

To see the `Security Credentials` tab, you need to click on the highlighted name of user.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has this same problem and the above solution doesn't work, make sure you choose the option "I want to create an IAM user" when checking the "Provide user access to the AWS Management Console - Optional".

Identity Center (based on my experience) does not allow key access.

[image: IAM User Creation Screenshot]